# Get device name from user agent infos within JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I know that there are a lot questions about this topic but none of them are helpful for me. I know, that I can't get the device via JavaScript like iPhone or so.

So when I run this command:

```
navigator.userAgent
```

I'm getting this result:

```
"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36"
```

Now I want to extract the first word `Macintosh` after the opening bracket and store it in a variable. How can I do this for example with RegEx?

Comment: Well, why not try something?

Comment: Because I don't know how to work with RegEx and if this is even possible

Comment: Of course it's possible. RegExp is pattern matching, precisely for cases such as this. So the first thing is to do a RegExp tutorial.

Comment: ([a-zA-Z]+;) This is what I've got but how can I get the ; out of it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

RegExp is all about defining the logic of your pattern. This means you need to be sure about the string format for it to work.

So for example, in the example you posted, perhaps we define the bit you want to match as:

- "the first word after the first opening bracket"

In which case:

```
navigator.userAgent.match(/^[^\(]+\((\w+)/);
```

Comment: This returns everything before ; but I just need Macintosh so maybe there is an error but I'll try it with your answer. Thanks for your help.

Comment: The first element of the match will always return the whole match, but the second element ([1]) will be just Macintosh.

Comment: Oh okay, I understand. And how can I access now the last element?

Comment: Well `match()` returns an array, as is surely evident. https://jsfiddle.net/2h6o3cfb/1/